# How to avoid name-clashes in xsds between BizTalk messages and WCF service datacontracts

Tags: wcf, xsd, biztalk, datacontract

Consider the following: I have BizTalk project and inside it I have placed xsd schemas for messages. 
Those schemas are in namespace "A". I have another web service, it uses datacontract with namespaces "A" too. 
So when I add a service reference to the first project which is Biztalk, VS generates schemas for datacontracts that are in the second project. 
Thus I have 2 schemas with the same namespace and root element.

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I re-titled your post. If you object I will change it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I can see your problem now. My question would then be why do you have the name-clash in the first place? If the generated schemas are generated from a running instance of your service then you do not need to code your own schemas, you can just use the generated ones.

Or, I can understand this a different way: the schemas you have developed are for a different purpose, but they just happen to share the same root node name and namespace as the generated schemas. In this case you should refactor your non-generated schemas by either changing the target namespace and/or the root node name.

It is best practise never to re-use target namespaces across messages in BizTalk server. Infact when you build your solution the compiler issues a warning when you do this.

Is this possible for you to do this?

Comment: To tell the truth I've already changed namespace of the datacontracts of the service I'm using and that fixed the problem. But I still want to know what is the best way to a) define a message type to work with in BizTalk and b) define datacontracts for that message for use in WCF service.

Comment: When you generate the datacontracts in your WCF service you should not be thinking about the biztalk side. Biztalk will generate all the biztalk messages you need to communicate with your service. Maybe I am completely missing the point of your question?